# Java - Command line to run a class with another jvm

Tags: java

I've java 1.8.0_131 by default on my machine but also java 9, so can I run a compiled class with jdk-9? is it possible anything like this:

```
    java -v path/to/jdk-9 myClass
```

Thanks

Comment: No. But you can use the standard way: `/path/to/jdk-9/bin/java MyClass`

Comment: No, this command is not possible. But you can run the class with the java command that comes with your Java9 installation.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can also change the default java version to always use jdk-9

Comment: are you using Windows Mac or Linux

Answer (score 1):

The `java` command actually invokes the JVM. That JVM starts up, and reads your classes, and runs what you tell it to run.

There is **no** way to tell the "starting" JVM to actually use a different JVM. `java` isn't some sort of wrapper that "later" invokes some binary. It is already the binary that starts the JVM.

In other words: what you are asking for isn't possible. A simple workaround can be to define "aliases" on the command line, like java-8 to start your java8 installation, and java-9 to point to that other installation.

Answer (score 0):

By default java command call the installed java version which can be checked by command:

One way could be update the java:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java.
```

O/P of above command:

```
  Selection    Path                                     Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode


 Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

In your case java 9 will also come. update java version and run java command.

Or you can do directly call your java9 script which you can find ${Java9 Installation Directory}/jre/bin/java -v class.

PS: Above description of commands is based on ubuntu.